# Create Active Directory contact without LDAP

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

How I can create AD contact without using LDAP and classes DirectoryEntry and DirectorySearcher.

Using LDAP I can do it easily with following code:

```
using (var userBinding = new DirectoryEntry(LDAP_PREFIX + connectionSettings.Context, connectionSettings.UserName, connectionSettings.Password))
{    
 {
    userBinding.RefreshCache();
    DirectoryEntry activeDirectoryContact;
    activeDirectoryContact = userBinding.Children.Add(String.Format("{0} {1}", LDAP_COMMONNAME, markDomaincontact.DisplayName), LDAP_OBJECTCLASS_CONTACT);
    activeDirectoryContact.CommitChanges();

 }
}
```

But completely not clear, how to do it without LDAP?

Comment: Why do you want to do it a different way? This is the standard...

Comment: Standard way to use LDAP?

Comment: Yes - LDAP is the way to go. I suppose you could host the Exchange PowerShell cmdlets and call them - they'd ultimately just make a series of LDAP calls, though.